# Google Chrome extensions document.title not working

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

here is the code in the manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Page Title changer",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Change the <title></title> of a page",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["changetitle.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is the code from the changetitle.js file

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    document.title = 'new page title';
});
```

i don't understand why it isn't working, i checked the google code docs while writing this extension.

Comment: if you wanna setup `document.title`, you must have `<title>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As detailed in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) you cannot use `chrome.*` API within content scripts except for some `chrome.extension.*` methods.

However, this doesn't really limit you as you can use [messaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to call your content script from your background page. For example;

**background.html**

```
<script type="application/javascript">
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {title: 'new page title'}, function (response) {});
    });
});
</script>
```

**changetitle.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    document.title = request.title;
});
```

You will of course require the [tabs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#manifest) permission in order to use this technique.

Answer (score 2):

This one will work in any URI Scheme

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Page Title changer",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Change the <title></title> of a page",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions": [
        "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**background.html**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: "changetitle.js"
    });
});
```

**changetitle.js**

```
document.title = 'new page title';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: "document.title = 'new page title'"
    });
});
```