# Document.title from parent page? (Chome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a really basic javascript extension for Google Chrome. I want to basically get the title/url/meta description off the current page. I use javascript `document.*` for this.

In theorie it works, but it doesn't do what I want. When loaded in the extension this just shows the information of the `popup.html` page, and not the info of the users current page.

How do I do this?

I found some related questions: [Google Chrome extensions document.title not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655608/google-chrome-extensions-document-title-not-working). I think I need to add some kind of `chrome.*` function?

This is my code:

---

popup.js

```
var title = document.title;
if (title.length > 69) {
    var title = title.substring(0,69);
    var title = title+" <strong>...</strong>";  
}

var url = document.URL;

var desc = document.getElementsByName('description')[0].getAttribute('content');
if (desc.length > 156) {
    var desc = desc.substring(0,156);
    var desc = desc+" <strong>...</strong>";    
}

document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = title;
document.getElementById('url').innerHTML = url;
document.getElementById('meta').innerHTML = desc;
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Preview</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Preview" />
    <style>
    body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;
    }

    #result { line-height: 1.2; width: 584px;}
    .r { margin:0px; padding:0px;}
    .r a { color:#2518b5; font-size:medium; font-weight:normal;}
    #url { color: #00802a; font-style: normal; }
    #meta { line-height:1.24; font-size: small; width:512px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result">
      <h3 class="r"><a href="" id="link">{title}</a></h3>
      <span id="url">{url}</span><br />
      <span class="st" id="meta">{meta}</span>
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Description here",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Preview",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to interact with the content page, you need to write a separate script file and register it in `content_scripts` in the manifest.

It can communicate with your popup by passing messages.

For more information, see the [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)